# Split string in Laravel Framework

Tags: php, database, laravel, split

How do I split string and display it in a table in Laravel Framework? I fetch data from my database that consists of one column but in a string such as `{ 1234, normal, r4r3r2 }`. I want to split it into three different parts/values by commas and display it in a table of three columns.

For now, I only can display the data without splitting the them.

My HomeController:

```
public function index()
  {
    $test = Test::all();
    return view('home')->with('test', $test);
  }
```

My home.blade.php:

```
<ol>
   @foreach($test as $row)
     <li>{{ $row->data }}</li>
   @endforeach
</ol>
```

Comment: just use explode . $data = explode(',', $row->data);

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First explode the $test variable  to get Array,

```
<ol>
 @foreach(explode(',',$test) as $row)
  <li>{{ $row }}</li>
 @endforeach
</ol>
```

After explode using foreach single key we can access from the array.
I hope it helps.

Comment: If it helps you then do not forget to upvote.
Thanks for accepting answer as right answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can explode you string in blade file like this

```
@foreach(explode(',', $row->data) as $fields) 
    <li>{{$fields}}</li>
@endforeach
```

And using of your model you can also done like this

```
class Test extends Model 
{
  public function getDataAttribute()
  {
    return explode(',', $this->data);
  }
}
```

it's return your data explode with comma separated array.